# jQuery Mobile collapsible set buggy behaviour

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile

When running the code below on android/ios, and tapping with two fingers on the same collapsible element, it lights up (as selected) until you tap it again. Same thing happens if you tap abit fast on different elements. I wonder how to fix this buggy behaviour.

Also it is slow to collapse and expand the elements, its not instant like it should be. What can the reason be?

I made a short vid where you can see the effects on a Sony Xperia Z3 Compact and iPhone 5S.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HiwzKwMt1jM

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="pageone">
    <div class="ui-content" data-role="main" style=
    "padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0;">
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" style="margin: 0;">
            <div class="divs" data-collapsed-icon="gear" data-expanded-icon=
            "gear" data-inset="false" data-role="collapsible">
                <h4 class="elem">12:00 Some concert</h4>

                <p>concert info</p>
            </div>

            <div class="divs" data-collapsed-icon="gear" data-expanded-icon=
            "gear" data-inset="false" data-role="collapsible">
                <h4 class="elem">13:00 Some other concert</h4>

                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p7g1q1qd/

Answer (score 0):

overriding the blue "active" css got rid of the buggy problem.

```
.ui-btn-active
{
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    border-color: #1f1f1f !important;
    background-color: #333 !important;
}
```